# AssemblyInfo.cs for WebSite in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, assemblies

I am using WebSite project in Visual Studio 2005. I don't see any AssemblyInfo.cs created for a WebSite project. Can I manually create AssemblyInfo.cs in a Properties folder there or is there any better way?

*Its an existing project so I can't change it now. I am maintaining this WebSite project and want to add log4Net using PostSharp.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AssemblyInfo.cs` is required to holds information for versioning the assembly. Normally you will provide your public key generated by the sn.exe utility and also a flag to delay sign or not.

ASP.NET websites are not compiled assembly rather interpreted (only first time). And thus such thing is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a web application project? With that type of project you will have an AssemblyInfo.cs.

Comment: Its an existing project so I can't change it now. I am maintaining this WebSite project and want to add log4Net using PostSharp.