# How to set the version of Web Site Assemblies

Tags: .net, asp.net, versioning

I created a Website in order to create a Web User Control as a DLL. Something similar to this http://www.nathanblevins.com/2008/06/compile-a-web-user-control-into-a-dll-net-c/

The problem is that i can't set the version of the assemblies, unlike a web application where i can just go to AssemblyInfo and change the version number.
I need to be able to manage the version number as we intend to install the controls to the GAC

Little help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Why* can't you just go into the AssemblyInfo and change the version number there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237622/assemblyinfo-cs-for-website-in-visual-studio-2005

Comment: Because it a Website (File > New Website) doesn't have an AssemblyInfo when created :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very useful article on MSDN which should help you: [How to: Create Versioned Assemblies for Precompiled Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228042.aspx)

Comment: I've been looking for this for quite some time now. Thanks for pointing it for me!